# What is the best Laravel package or plugin for social login/signup feature?

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, package

I want to add login/signup feature on my website. Is there any **official** or **best** package for laravel which i can use?

Comment: Laravel has already it's ows login register scaffolder, and for socials you can use Socialite i believe https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Laravel has it's own official package for social login/signup feature called **Socialite**.

**Here's the link.**

> https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite

Answer (score 0):

Laravel app using Socialite a package built by Laravel for social authentication. Socialite currently supports authentication with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google, GitHub, and Bitbucket.
Here is the link:-

[Social Login In Laravel With Socialite](https://medium.com/@Alabuja/social-login-in-laravel-with-socialite-90dbf14ee0ab)